# Using intersectionObserver instead of onscroll event

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

my-div element has position absolute. When you scroll the page, as soon as my-div is out of the view port its position changes to fixed and top: 0. Here I need to change the value 0 for top to 100px.

I managed to do so by using **onscroll** method as follow:

```
document.onscroll = function(){
    const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div')
    if(myDiv && myDiv.style.position == 'fixed') {
        myDiv.style.top = '100px';
    }
}
```

The above code is working. However, the problem with this code is that it fires on each scroll event and is bad for performance.
Now I'm trying to use **intersectionObserver** method instead of onscroll method.

What I need is:
As soon as my-div isn't in the viewport and its position is fixed, add top 100px to it.

I tried this:

```
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.my-div');
  if (myDiv) {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting === false &&  myDiv.style.position == 'fixed') {
          myDiv.style.top = '100px';
          observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
      });
    });

    observer.observe(myDiv);
  }
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible demo?

Comment: I can't see where the div's position is set to fixed.

Comment: You should listen window onload event,then execute Intersection Observer callback.
[mdn intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure I get your question. `position: fixed` means that element always sticks within the viewport even though you try to scroll away. I think you need to clarify more about your situation like why you need it

Comment: Guys forget about position fixed. I just want that if the object is out of view its top gets the value 100px. And I want to know how to achieve this with intersectionObserver.

Comment: You can gain performance by moving the  queryselector part to the outside of the handler

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if an entry is no longer in viewport, use [`.intersectionRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserverEntry/intersectionRatio) property, if the value is 0 then it's not in the viewport:

```
if (entries[0].intersectionRatio <= 0) {
```

In the example below, scroll down and once the red square is no longer in viewport, it will be stuck at 100px from the top of viewport. Also added a semi-transparent background to serve as a easily noticeable style that confirms that the code functions as requested (ie change styles of a `<div>` once it is no longer within the viewport).

```js
const X = document.querySelector('.X');

const obr = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  if (entries[0].intersectionRatio <= 0) {
    X.style.cssText = `position: fixed; top: 100px; background: rgba(255, 36, 0, 0.3)`;
    this.unobserve(X);
  }
});

obr.observe(X);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%
}

html {
  font: 5vmax/1.375 Consolas;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 300vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.X {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50vh - 2.25rem);
  left: calc(50% - 2.25rem);
  z-index: 1;
  width: 4.5rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  border: 5px groove tomato;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 5px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#top {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#top+a {
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}

#mid {
  top: calc(150vh - 2.25rem);
  left: calc(50% - 2.25rem);
  width: 4.5rem;
  height: 4.5rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

#mid+a {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0
}

#sub {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <a href='#sub' id='top'>SUB</a>
  <a href='#mid'>MID</a>

  <div class='X'></div>
  <a id='mid'>❌</a>

  <a href='#mid'>MID</a>
  <a href='#top' id='sub'>TOP</a>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks zer0ne. By looking at your example I was able to fix my issue. But what if I wanted to change the styling after the element is outside of the viewport + 60px ?

Comment: That's great @user1941537, don't forget to accept this answer by clicking the green ✅. Do you mean a total of 160px? You just change  `top: 100px` to `160px`.

Comment: Hello, @zer00ne could you take a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75204977/intersectionobserver-to-create-a-lazy-load-images-with-data-srcset-and-imagekit

Answer (score 0):

I found that `.intersectionRatio` can be unpredictable during very fast scrolling and mouse-wheeling (and touch-gestures) in some browsers.

`.isIntersecting` is a much more reliable and performant solution than `.intersectionRatio`.

```
const obr = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
  if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) { //<- this
    //do stuff
  }
});
```